# Using pdf generated in a standalone documentclass in an other project

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, overleaf, standalone, output

So I have this big project on Overleaf, and I need to import bar chart from another project. I'm using `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` to generate my bar charts. Everything is working great at this point.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} % Les barres %
    
\begin{filecontents}{AAA.csv}
ABS,AAA,BBB
CCC,             53,          26
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{DDD.csv}
ABS,DDD,EEE
FFF,             63,          58
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{AAA.csv}{\loadedtable}
\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\loadedtable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NoOfCols}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
        
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines =left,
        width=1.2*\axisdefaultwidth,
        height=\axisdefaultheight,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=65,
        ybar=2pt,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{ABS},
        bar width=0.70/\NoOfCols,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.6},
        legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north east},
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfkeys{
                /pgf/fpu=true,
                /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed,
            }
            \pgfmathparse{
                ifthenelse(
                    \pgfplotspointmeta < 1000,
                    \pgfplotspointmeta,
                    \pgfplotspointmeta/1000
                )
            }
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Y}{\pgfplotspointmeta}
            \ifnum\Y<1000
                \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,
            \else
                \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,
            \fi
        },
        point meta=rawy,
    ]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\NoOfCols} {
            \addplot table [
                x expr=\coordindex,
                y index=\i,
                col sep=comma,
            ] {\loadedtable};
                \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{\i}\of{\loadedtable}\to{\colname}
                \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{DDD.csv}{\loadedtable}
\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\loadedtable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NoOfCols}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
        
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines =left,
        width=1.2*\axisdefaultwidth,
        height=\axisdefaultheight,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=65,
        ybar=2pt,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{ABS},
        bar width=0.70/\NoOfCols,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.6},
        legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north east},
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfkeys{
                /pgf/fpu=true,
                /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed,
            }
            \pgfmathparse{
                ifthenelse(
                    \pgfplotspointmeta < 1000,
                    \pgfplotspointmeta,
                    \pgfplotspointmeta/1000
                )
            }
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Y}{\pgfplotspointmeta}
            \ifnum\Y<1000
                \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,
            \else
                \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,
            \fi
        },
        point meta=rawy,
    ]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\NoOfCols} {
            \addplot table [
                x expr=\coordindex,
                y index=\i,
                col sep=comma,
            ] {\loadedtable};
                \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{\i}\of{\loadedtable}\to{\colname}
                \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So I have my 2 bar charts

[image]

Then I go to my "real" document and import my pdf from my standalone project. This is the issue, when I chose to import from the generated pdf, the menu propose only one pdf. I would like to have the choice between 2 pdf one with each bar chart. **And I don't know how to code in the standalone document the fact that I want 2 pdf generated instead of one.**

[image]

And to conclude, when I go to my "real" document and code this :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I have only one of the 2 bar chart ..

[image]

Sorry if the question has been already asked .. Thanks for the hepl !

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz,multi]{standalone}` should normally create a document with more than one page.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working, I think, in the tikz option, it's set to generage one page for each tikzpicture.. I would like to hace one different pdf generated for each page.. But I hace no idea if it's possible ^^

Comment: no not really. You would need two documents and as overleaf always create output.pdf you would have to store the one before creating the other. Putting everything in one pdf and then selecting the page is imho easier.

Comment: `\includegraphics[page=1,...]{...}`, `\includegraphics[page=2, ...]{...}`

Comment: Oooh thank you, can't belive it was that simple... I'm sorry, I really should of found this by myself !

Comment: @Cla-Jan Don't worry. I don't know where it is documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close de question, it was in fact very simple :

```
\includegraphics[page=1,...]{...}, \includegraphics[page=2, ...]{...}
```

Thanks to Ignasi in the comments.